# How can I disconnect a serial port from a child form?

Tags: c#

I am updating a C# rogram that measures alpha and beta radiation. The port is connected in a parent form (HomeForm) in C#. The parent form has child forms such as sampling counting, QC, and calibration. The current option to disconnect a connected port and to connect to different port in a child window is to exit from a parent form and to open it again to connect a new port from a parent form.

My question is as follows: (1) Can I disconnect a port from a child window, which is connected from a parent window? (2) If the question (1) is possible, what is the method to do it in C#?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Inseok Baek

```
public bool Get_Coms(string PortToConnect) 
{
  return Get_Coms(PortToConnect, 8, Parity.None, 115200, Handshake.None, StopBits.One);
}

public bool Get_Coms(string PortToConnect, int DataBits, Parity parity, int baudrate, Handshake handshake, StopBits stopbits)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: can you show some of the code you are using? And what you've tried, if you've tried anything so far?

Comment: From the sketchy information you provide, the disconnecting and connecting code is probably in the parent form exit and open events. There is no reason why you couldn't move that code to some other events eg a connect button and a disconnect button.

Comment: The class in parent form is written as:

Comment: User wants to disconnect a serial port from a child form instead of going up to a parent form and exiting from a parent form to connect to another port. I use like:         public bool Get_Coms(string PortToConnect) //Overload with default communication instance.
        {
            return Get_Coms(PortToConnect, 8, Parity.None, 115200, Handshake.None, StopBits.One);
        }
        
        public bool Get_Coms(string PortToConnect, int DataBits, Parity parity, int baudrate, Handshake handshake, StopBits stopbits)
        {
            if (this.Connected)
            {

Comment: Pass a delegate between the two forms.  The child form can invoke the delegate, which causes code in the parent to run and disconnect the port which it owns.  There are many ways to accomplish this: event, public member variable, constructor parameter.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for comment. Would you send me an example to baek_inseok@Hotmail.com? I would greatly appreciate if you send me an example method. Thanks again. Inseok

Comment: @InseokBaek asking people to send code to you via email is very rude. This is a Q&A site, answers need to be on the site, not sent to people in emails. If you don't care enough about your question to come back here to check for answers we should not care enough either to give you answers.

Comment: I apologize my request. Thanks, Scott for your good advise. I am looking at delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to the child form and subscribe to that event in the parent.  I assume you're adding a button for the user to click to disconnect the port, when the user clicks that button you'd raise the event so the parent form can decide what to do about it.

```
public class ChildForm()
{
    ... existing form code ...

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DisconnectClicked;

    protected void Disconnect_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(DisconnectClicked != null)
       {
           DisconnectClicked(this, new EventArgs());
       }
    }
}

public class ParentForm()
{
    public void ShowChildForm()
    {
        ... existing code to show child ...
        child.DisconnectClicked += (sender, args) => 
        {  
            // call existing code in parent form that disconnects the port
            DisconnectPort() 
        };

       child.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will have to add "disconnect" button. I will test this method and will come back with updated code. After making disconnect button click, can I write : SP = new SerialPort(); SP.Close(); . I haven't write a disconnect code. Instead I exited to disconnect code by : this.Dispose(); Thanks again. Inseok

Comment: I am a beginner in C#. I am a nuclear engineer. Should disconnect button be created in a parent form or both a parent and a child form? Thanks.